# How to average every 3 columns with NA in R

Tags: r, matrix, average

I have a matrix with NA and I want to find the mean of every 3 columns for each row.

```
set.seed(100)
a <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:4), 90, replace = TRUE), 10)
```

If I use

```
t(apply(a, 1, tapply, gl(3, 3), mean))
```

The code cannot find the average for colums including NA. I wonder how I can modify the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `t(apply(a, 1, tapply, gl(3, 3), mean, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: I am an idiot, haha, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by also converting to a 3D array and then get the `rowMeans` after looping through the 3rd MARGIN.

```
res <- apply(array(a, c(nrow(a), 3, 3)), 3, rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
all.equal(res, t(apply(a, 1, tapply, gl(3, 3), 
       mean, na.rm = TRUE)), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What does `c(nrow(a), 3, 3)` mean? Thanks.

Comment: @YangYang  3D array have 3 dimensions, where first is the row, second column, and the 3rd dimension.  here, the number of rows is same as that of the original matrix.  So I specified it as `nrow(a)`, the next is 3, as we want only 3 columns in each array slice

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!